# How do i get to know when I fail to enter a duplicate database entry?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I'm using Spring Data JPA with Hibernate.

I have a class with a composite key mapped to a database table.

When I perform a save operation using the JPARepository extended interface object, I see the following log in the console:

```
Hibernate: select rolefuncti0_.functionalityId as function1_4_0_, rolefuncti0_.roleId as roleId2_4_0_ from RoleFunctionality_Mapping rolefuncti0_ where rolefuncti0_.functionalityId=? and rolefuncti0_.roleId=?
Hibernate: insert into RoleFunctionality_Mapping (functionalityId, roleId) values (?, ?)
```

This is what I see when i repeat the operation with the same data:

```
 Hibernate: select rolefuncti0_.functionalityId as function1_4_0_, rolefuncti0_.roleId as roleId2_4_0_ from RoleFunctionality_Mapping rolefuncti0_ where rolefuncti0_.functionalityId=? and rolefuncti0_.roleId=?
```

It appears Spring Data first checks whether the Key exists in the database, and then proceeds to perform insertion.

There should be a way to catch the information which hibernate has found (that the database entry/key exists in the database)? How can we check that?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such way. Hibernate can not determine if the primary key exists except it would issue a SQL query itself. Hibernate assumes that this check is done by the application logic to allow this to become a matter of performance optimization.

The only chance Hibernate has to notice of duplicated key problems is a SQLException from the database (or the JDBC layer) informing about a unique constraint violation of the id field. And as always one should consider a Hibernate session as invalid if a SQLException occured (since Hibernate can not ensure a valid state taking interceptor and listener processing into account).

So the spring way of issuing an extra query is the way to go unless you can provide additional logic to ensure the key is not already present in the database by using additional counters, getting and reserving free ids in bulk or using application wide event / messaging solution to synchronize entity id allocation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I can appreciate what Spring does here. I was thinking there should be some kind of information which would be possible to get from Spring that it would return/give in any other way to the application- if it is not going to go ahead with insertion in the event of a duplicate entry. (Spring makes a decision (based on some information) not to insert after finding an existing primary key.)